# Convert pandas dataframe to dict to JSON, unflatten nested subkeys, drop None/NaN keys

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, nested

Can the following be done in Pandas in one go, in more Pythonic code than below?

I have a row from a pandas-dataframe:

- some values may be NaNs or empty strings or similar
- I'd like to map this information to a dict (which is then converted to JSON and passed on to another application)
- However, NaNs should not be included in the dict. (By default they are passed as `None`)
- Dict subkeys `'c.x', 'c.y', 'c.z'` should be unflattened, i.e. converted to a subdict `c` with keys `x, y, z`. Again, NaN keys in each row should be dropped.

**Sample input:** I iterate over rows in a dataframe with `row = next(df.iterrows())`, where a sample row would look like:

```
a        3
b      NaN
c.x      4
c.y      5
c.z    NaN
```

**Desired output**

```
{"A": 3,
"C": {"X": 4, "Y": 5}}
```

The most natural way (to me) to do that would like something like this:

```
outdict={"A": row['a'] if not pandas.isna(row['a']) else None,
    "B": row['b'] if not pandas.isna(row['b']) else None,
    "C": {"X": row['c.x'] if not pandas.isna(row['c.x']) else None,
        "Y": row['c.y'] if not pandas.isna(row['c.y']) else None,
        "Z": row['c.z'] if not pandas.isna(row['c.z']) else None
}}
```

However, this still assigns `None` to the slots that I'd like to remain empty (the receiving application is difficult in handlings `nulls`).

One workaround would be using this code and subsequently removing all None values in a second pass, or I could use `outdict.update` for each value (and not update if the value is `NaN`). But both solutions seems not very efficient to me.

Comment: Does your dataframe have a row with that text in or is that two columns from the dataframe? So a,b etc. are in one column and the values are in another?

Comment: recursive function would do I guess what you looking for.

Comment: @TBurgis, I meant it as row as given by a rowiterator (`row=next(df.iterrows`), from a dataframe with 5 columns, named a, b, c.x, c.y and c.z.

Comment: Your title is very misleading: strictly you don't just want to "assign to some keys in a dict", **the bigger part of your question is you want to create subdicts 'c' for 'c.x, c.y, c.z'**, which pandas and json code doesn't usually handle. Also you want to drop NaN keys.

Comment: For unflattening subdicts, see the [10 questions on \[python\] unflatten dict](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+unflatten+dict+is%3Aquestion). Presumably helpful for JSON if it also drops `None` keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To transform your DataFrame to a dictionary without NaN, there is a straightforward way:

```
df.dropna().to_dict()
```

But you also want to create sub-dictionaries from composed keys, and I found no other way than a loop:

```
df = DataFrame({"col": [3, None, 4, 5, None]}, index=["a", "b", "c.x", "c.y", "c.z"])
d = df.dropna().to_dict()
```

`d` is:

```
{'col': {'a': 3.0, 'c.x': 4.0, 'c.y': 5.0}}
```

Then:

```
d2 = dict()
for k, v in d['col'].items(): 
     if k.count('.'): 
         a, b = k.split('.') 
         d2.setdefault('a', {}) 
         d2[a][b] = v 
     else: 
         d2[k] = v
```

and `d2` is:

```
{'a': 3.0, 'c': {'y': 5.0, 'x': 4.0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `row` is a `Series` object, the following code will not create any entries for NaNs:

```
outdict = {row.index[i]: row[i]
           for i in range(data.shape[1])
           if not pandas.isna(row[i])}
```

However, it won't create the nested structure that you want. There are several ways I can think of to solve this, none of which are extremely elegant. The best way I can think of is to exclude the columns with labels of the form `a.b` when creating `outdict`; *i.e.*

```
outdict = {row.index[i]: row[i]
           for i in range(data.shape[1])
           if not (pandas.isna(row[i]) or '.' in row.index[i])}
```

then create the subdicts individually and assign them in outdict.